# How to call function as well route change using Navilink with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

when a person click on a navigation in popup, i need to close the popup as well required to route in to new page. but click function works. but "to" function not routing to new page. what is the correct way to do this?

here is my compoenent:

method:

```
 toggle = (e:React.MouseEvent):void =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({show:!prevState.show}));
    }
```

it works fine from here:

```
<a className="nav-icon hidden" onClick={this.toggle} href="#">tantum-Menu</a>
```

but not the `to` works from here:

```
 <li><NavLink to="about-us" onClick={e => this.toggle}>About us</NavLink></li>
```

`about-us` page not loading. how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

What you used for Router? e.i:

```
<Route path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
```

then:

```
<NavLink to="/about-us" onClick={e => this.toggle}>About us</NavLink>
```

Comment: Not works.. but in case of other function it works fine